# Can I save this hard drive?

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, 22.04

I tried to create a dual boot with Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows 10, but I messed up and somehow lost the boot sector. I ran "disk repair" in Ubuntu, then started a new installation (so I could leave Windows behind). The Ubuntu installer said it needed to create partition(s), so I let it start. That was two days ago. The Ubuntu installer screen has remained stuck at this screen ever since.

[image: PC Screen after two days]

Answer (score 1):

I am uncertain as to the "WHY", but installing Ubuntu choosing the "Manufacturer Only" installation option solved the problem.  The drive portion of the install only took about 5 minutes this way.  I am appreciative for this resource and the people who tried to help me!  Thank you!!